# PFQueryTableViewController in Swift using Cloud Code function

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to convert a simple UITableViewController to PFQueryTableViewController in Swift.  So far I know I have to initialise my class like that: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069921/use-pfquerytableviewcontroller-from-parse-with-swift))

```
class TestTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(className aClassName: String!) {
    super.init(className: aClassName)

    self.parseClassName = aClassName
    self.textKey = "YOUR_PARSE_COLOMN_YOU_WANT_TO_SHOW"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}
}
```

I have two problems:

- somehow I cannot import PFQueryTableViewController
- I would like to use a cloud function for feeding my table instead of a Query object.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In bridging header for Swift you need to import "ParseUI.h" as below. Then you need to initialize the class name in 'init:coder'

```
#import '<ParseUI/ParseUI.h>'
```

Init of PFQueryTableViewController class object

```
override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "MyClass"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 50
}
```

```

Regarding the second question, if you are about to use the Parse Cloud Function so there's no need to use the `PFQueryTableViewController` class. Just using the normal `UITableViewController` and run your cloud function upon controller initialization

Comment: thanks for you answer. About the second point, I would be interested in the paging functionality of the PFQueryTableViewController so I was wondering if there is anyway to pass this class a PFCloud function instead of a PFQuery

Comment: Thanks @Wajatimur - That extra import caught me out.