# Initializing Parse.com Table View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I recently began using Parse.com with swift and I am trying to create a simple app loading data into a table. In using the class PFQueryTableViewController, I found that the following code must be used:

```
override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.parseClassName = "MyClass"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 50
}
```

My question is why must initialization of this class be called twice? and what are these initializations accomplishing?

*Code was taken from this question:
[PFQueryTableViewController in Swift using Cloud Code function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239101/pfquerytableviewcontroller-in-swift-using-cloud-code-function)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization is not called twice; by defining two initializers you define two different ways to initialize an object. It's like with `NSNumber`:

- `init(float: Float)`
- `init(double: Double)`
- `init(bool: Bool)`
- and 13 more...

You use only one of them when initializing your `NSNumber` instance.

---

The requirement of `init?(coder: NSCoder)` is a different topic, discussed in the following questions:

- [Class does not implement its superclass's required members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members)
- [Fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(coder:)' for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class)